# ASP.NET MVC - Import Item with Parent Category from Excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this Excel sheet as shown below

[image: Excel sheet]

The table is shown below

[image: Table with data]

I want to import from the Excel and save into the database using ASP.NET MVC.
From the Excel, when it is Level 1(Root Category), then ParentID will be 0.

1. ParentID1 is the Level - It can get to level N
2. ParentID of the Root Category(Level 1) will be set to 0
3. CategoryID is System Generated (auto-increment)
4. ParentID of the Child Category will be the CategoryID of the direct parent

Please how do I import this data from the Excel and save into the database. 
I started a code but don't know how to complete it, because of the complexity.

**Model**

```
    public partial class CategoryLevel
{
    public long CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string OPTION_VALUE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
        public ActionResult ImportCountriesExcel(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
    {
        string data = "";
        var bodsList = new List<CategoryLevel>();
        if (FileUpload != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["FileUpload"];
            if (true)
            {
                    string message = "";
                    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(FileUpload.InputStream))
                    {
                        var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                        // if(currentSheet.Count)
                        var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                        var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                        var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                        for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                        {
                            var bod = new CategoryLevel();
                            bod.CategoryName = Convert.ToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value).Trim();
                            bod.ParentID = Convert.ToInt(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value);
            bod.ParentID1 = Convert.ToInt(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value);
            bod.ParentID2 = Convert.ToInt(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value);

                            bodsList.Add(bod);
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (var item in bodsList)
                    {
                        _categorylevelService.AddCategoryLevel(item);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

> How do I import these complex data from Excel sheet, and do the manipulations, and the save into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you don't have technical issues, it's more about how to process it logically. StackOverflow is not the *perfect* place to ask this kind of questions, but I can give you some advice.

Some difficulties will be in the Model. Because you don't really store a structure (this would require to use Navigational Properties etc.) you always need to store the Parent Item first to gather it's ID, because you will need it for the child record.

A good way to import data (in general) is to put it into a temporary model structure where you can run some mass queries on it etc.

You could create a Class to perfectly reflect the Excel Schema:

```
public class MyExcelRow
{
    public string Level1Code { get; set; }
    public string Level1Name { get; set; }

    public string Level2Code { get; set; }
    public string Level2Name { get; set; }

    public string Level3Code { get; set; }
    public string Level3Name { get; set; }

    public string Level4Code { get; set; }
    public string Level4Name { get; set; }
}
```

You should be able to populate it yourself easily.

Now the most interesting point is you manage a `List<MyExcelRow>` and with the Magic of LINQ you can execute queries on the collection, example, get all Level-1 Items:

```
var level1Items = myExcelRowList.Where(x => x.Level1Name != null).Select(x => new { ThisItem = x, ParentItem = null });
```

So you would do that and send them all to the Database.
In the next step, you get the Level-2 Items, and you know that the parent is Level-1.

```
var level1Items = myExcelRowList.Where(x => x.Level2Name != null).Select(x => new { ThisItem = x, ParentItem = x.Level1Name });
```

Of course, there are different approaches, but more sophisticated (aggregation based, recursion based...), and I tried to pick one for you which would be easy enough to understand.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ClosedXML to solve your Issue.

[image]

but in that you need to Provide header name to Each column then only it will work.

> Demo Excel File which you where Reading.

[image]

> Dataset View After Reading File

[image]

Code For Reading Excel Using ClosedXML

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection frm)
{
    string strPhotoUpload = "UploadExcel";
    HttpPostedFileBase image = Request.Files[strPhotoUpload];
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    var img = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
    if (image != null && image.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fullpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/"),System.IO.Path.GetFileName(image.FileName));
        image.SaveAs(fullpath);

        using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(fullpath))
        {
            //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
            IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);
            //Create a new DataTable.
            //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
            bool firstRow = true;
            foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
            {
                //Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
                if (firstRow)
                {
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    firstRow = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(workSheet.FirstCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber, workSheet.LastCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber))
                    {
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var dd = dt;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: What I understand from the Question is that the opener has difficulties especially to "unflatten" the structure and get it into his Model. So this would be only the half of the job

Comment: @Ayobamilaye you did mark as answer does it worked for you or not

Comment: Am new, and have short time for this project. Can you go a bit further in the code. Am getting very interested in the flow of how you are doing it